# New action with form in one_of_many-to-one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Can't figure out how to render new action. When I'm trying to load new action, I get next error - `undefined method 'hotel' for nil:NilClass`

My trip, hotelseller and hotel models

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotelsellers, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :hotelsellers_attributes, :description
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotelsellers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a.blank? }
end

class Hotelseller < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  has_one :hotel

  attr_accessible :hotel_attributes,
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotel, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a.blank? }
end


class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotelseller

  attr_accessible :description
end
```

My controller **trips_controller.rb**

```
def new
  hotelseller_first = @trip.hotelsellers.build(five_stars: false)
  hotelseller_second = @trip.hotelsellers.build(five_stars: true)
  @hotel = @trip.hotelsellers.build.build_hotel
end
```

My form **new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@trip) do |f| %>
  <%- f.description %>
  <%= f.fields_for :hotelsellers do |builder| %> 

    <% if builder.object.five_stars %>
      First hotel
      <%= builder.hidden_field :five_stars, value: true %>
    <% else %>
  Second hotel
  <%= builder.hidden_field :five_stars, value: false %>
    <% end %>
    <%= builder.descritpion %>

    <%= builder.simple_fields_for :hotel do |builder| %>    
      <%= builder.description %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you provide stack trace.

Comment: @zishe 
`app/models/hotelseller.rb:10:in 'hotel'
app/views/trips/_hotelsellers_fields.html.erb:1:in '_app_views_trips__hotelsellers_fields_html_erb___4557694001198736098_69933781179120'
app/views/trips/new.html.erb:36:in 'block (2 levels) in _app_views_trips_new_html_erb__3198870636243357601_69933781728200'
app/views/trips/new.html.erb:28:in 'block in _app_views_trips_new_html_erb__3198870636243357601_69933781728200'
app/views/trips/new.html.erb:3:in '_app_views_trips_new_html_erb__3198870636243357601_69933781728200'`

Comment: in your controller, where did you define `@trip`? which line is the error message pointing to. I can't see anywhere that you calling the `hotel` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should change builder.simple_fields_for :hotel to builder.simple_fields_for :hotel_attributes